# Finding and Replacing media URLs embeded into WordPress pages but ignoring specific URLs

Tags: javascript, php, regex, wordpress, replace

I am working on a WordPress site where the content will be replaced each week (any posts, media or files are wiped from the WP environment each week, and then repopulated with all new content, and so on). One of the main features of the post pages, is that I will have to copy and paste local URLs from a Word document directly into the WordPress post. Since the original hyperlinks lead to a file saved on my local system, the hyperlinks obviously do not link properly on the WordPress site (no fear... I can handle this issue).

That is why using Regex *(essentially finds everything that is contained between "/ /")* in a small JavaScript function, I find all my hyperlinks on the post pages and replace the root directory to my WP server root directory (leaving file names at the end of URLs unaffected). This code works perfectly when placed in my "single.php" file as these type of hyperlinks will only be on single posts anyways.

Here is the code of the function described above:

```
<p><a href="https://test-wpserver/wordpress/2022/07/20/is-that-because-there-is-no-title/tab%201/FILE-(NAME-CODE02).pdf">Link 1</a></p>

<p><a href="https://test-wpserver/wordpress/tab-1-name-here/">Tab 1</a></p>
```

```
var changePermalinks = function() {
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
       oldPattern = /^[/\\\\]?(?:.+[/\\\\]+?)?(.+?)[/\\\\]/g,
       len = a.length,
       i;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       var link = a[i];
       var url = link.href;
       if (oldPattern.test(url)) {
           link.setAttribute('href', url.replace(oldPattern, 'https://hq-wpserver/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/content/'));
       } 
   }
};

changePermalinks();
```

Here is the JSFiddle of the code if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/3y9bpo25/

**THE MAIN PROBLEM:**

The issue is the code seems to be affecting every link on the single posts pages, including the links in my Nav menu. **I want all my Tab URLs to be left alone (the second link in the HTML section of code).** I have been working on this on and off for weeks now and can not seem to figure out how to fix my problem.

The two possible solutions I have tried to work out (with no luck) include:

1. Simply ignoring links that are not in the main post part of the page (essentially any links in the NAV menu)
2. Creating an if-else statement or switch case that finds specific URLs or strings (the exact page URL as a string) and ignores them, but replaces every other URL.

I feel like I have tested a million concepts and gotten no where... any help would be very much appreciated (or even another possible solution I can try to work out). Feel free to ask any questions that helps clarify the issue!

Comment: If you can place all your content in something with a unique identifier (either a literal ID or a specific class or HTML tag) you can use something like `document.querySelector('#main').getElementsByTagName('a')`